# CalendarView get only today's events

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with the graph in PHP, and building a calendar widget for a site that should pull only today's events, including all day events.

Everything works, however it also pulls all day events for yesterday and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
$today = new DateTime( 'now', new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York' ) );
$tomorrow = new DateTime( 'tomorrow', new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York' ) );

$start_date = $today->format('Y-m-d');
$end_date = $tomorrow->format('Y-m-d');

$events = ms_get_data_as_json( 'calendarview?startdatetime=' . $start_date . '&enddatetime=' . $end_date . '&$orderby=start/DateTime' );
```

the formatted request string outputs as `calendarview?startdatetime=2018-05-18&enddatetime=2018-05-19&$orderby=start/DateTime` which would appear to work correctly, however sending this request, the first object returned is an all day event for the previous day. See sample output:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [createdDateTime] => 2018-05-18T13:30:37.8672462Z
    [lastModifiedDateTime] => 2018-05-18T13:34:25.2248155Z
    [categories] => Array
        (
        )

    [originalStartTimeZone] => UTC
    [originalEndTimeZone] => UTC
    [reminderMinutesBeforeStart] => 1080
    [isReminderOn] => 
    [hasAttachments] => 
    [subject] => Test yesterday
    [bodyPreview] => 
    [importance] => normal
    [sensitivity] => normal
    [isAllDay] => 1
    [isCancelled] => 
    [isOrganizer] => 1
    [responseRequested] => 1
    [seriesMasterId] => 
    [showAs] => free
    [type] => singleInstance
    [onlineMeetingUrl] => 
    [recurrence] => 
    [responseStatus] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => organizer
            [time] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
        )

    [body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contentType] => html
            [content] => 

        )

    [start] => stdClass Object
        (
            [dateTime] => 2018-05-17T00:00:00.0000000
            [timeZone] => UTC
        )

    [end] => stdClass Object
        (
            [dateTime] => 2018-05-18T00:00:00.0000000
            [timeZone] => UTC
        )

)
```

The start property is clearly for the prior date.

I've tried to change my query to include timestamps `startdatetime=2018-05-18T00:00:01Z&enddatetime=2018-05-18T23:59:59Z` yet I still get the same results. I've tried to change my `$today` and `$tomorrow` variables to use UTC, as the returned result says `OriginalStartTimeZone` is UTC, but I still get the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit of an inequality problem in the way the apply the start/end dates filters, and it ends up including events that end on the start time (or start on the end time).

At the moment, it seems the solution is to add 1 second to the filter's start time, and subtract 1 second from the filter's end time. You'll still get all-day events for the requested date, but not all-day events for the previous or next day.

Let us know if you find situations which don't work with this method!

Comment: This is likely the cleanest solution. its silly that the start date time is 00:00:00 and the end date is also 00:00:00 for the next date, instead of something like 23:59:59, but there is probably some other reason happening in the background